# Should a react component have the knowledge of the state of its parent component

Tags: checkbox, reactjs, components

So I wrote this table row component  that comes with checkbox as the first column to be used by other table components. Below is a simplified version of the components

Table Row:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Checkbox } from 'react-bootstrap'

export default class TableRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleClickCheckbox = this.handleClickCheckbox.bind(this)
  }

  handleClickCheckbox() {
    this.props.onClickCheckbox(this.props.entity.id)
  }

  render() {
    const { checked, children } = this.props 

    return (
      <tr>
        <Checkbox
          checked={checked}
          onChange={this.handleClickCheckbox}
        >&nbsp;</Checkbox>
        {children}
      </tr>
    }

}
TableRow.propTypes = {
  entity: PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number
  }),
  checked: PropTypes.bool,
  onClickCheckbox: PropTypes.func
}
```

Table:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap'
import TableRow from './TableRow'

class SampleTable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      checkedEntitiesIds: []
    }
    this.handleChangeChecked = this.handleChangeChecked.bind(this)
  }

  handleChangeChecked(id) {
    const { checkedEntitiesIds } = this.state
    const indexOfEntity = checkedEntitiesIds.indexOf(id)
    // uncheck it if it's already checked, vice versa
    this.setState({
      checkedEntitiesIds : indexOfEntity > -1 ?
      checkedEntitiesIds.filter((id, index) => index != indexOfEntity) :
      [...checkedEntitiesIds, id]
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { entities } = this.props // can come from either parent component or subcribe to redux state
    return (
      <Table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>placeholder for checkbox column</th>
            <th>dummy header 1</th>
            <th>dummy header 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {entities.map(entity => 
          <TableRow
            key={entity.id}
            entity={entity}
            checked={this.state.checkedIds.indexOf(action.id) > -1}
            onClickCheckbox={this.handleChangeChecked}
          >
            <td>dummy table cell 1</td>
            <td>dummy table cell 2</td>
          </TableRow>
        )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    )
  }
}
```

I made the checkbox a controlled input since the value of checked props may come from database. Each table row has an entity props that can uniquely identify the row. I maintain the checkedEntitiesIds state in table components rather than maintain a checked state in the TableRow component since I feel it provides me the maximum flexibility.

One of my coworker doesn't like the fact that he has to maintain that checkedEntitiesIds state as well as handleChangeChecked function in every table component. He made a proposal of adding the checkedEntitiesIds state into TableRow and moving the function body of handleChangeChecked to TableRow. The way it works is every time a checkbox gets clicked/changed the checkedEntitiesIds state within TableRow will get updated first, and then gets passed back to parent table so checkedEntitiesIds state of the parent component gets updated too. That way he doesn't need to write the check/uncheck logic over and over.

Several things bother me to make such changes:

1. Making TableRow have knowledge of the checkedEntitiesIds, which is supposed to be a state of Table is so counter-intuitive.
2. Duplicate sources of truth.
3. TableRow will have a state. Correct me if I am wrong here. My understanding is those lower order dumb components should rarely have its own state.
4. In some scanerios, a checkbox click event might not necessarily lead to state change right away. For example, prompt a confirm modal first when checkbox gets clicked and update the state only if yes is chosen. Using state within TableRow doesn't provide such flexibility.

I am almost certain that his proposal is somewhat anti-pattern. I am just not sure if the way I put the components makes sense and whether those points I listed are valid. Am I missing any important stuff here to persuade him? Is there any way to improve my code in terms of reusability. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the points you've brought up seem legit. The Smart vs Dumb Component pattern seems to be the one that everyone is adopting (and for good reason, code gets really messy when there isn't this clear separation).

Another thing that is fundamentally wrong with your coworkers suggestion is the fact that there's an upward flow of data from child to parent. One of the core ideas of React is a **unidirectional data flow**. Changes in a child that is to propagate to the parent is supposed to **go through the store** (or whatever your data layer is) to maintain this unidirectional property.

[React Data Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr8AM.png)

With having the child notify the parent of updates, it adds a layer of complication (what if it triggers an update of a child, which goes back to the parent and loops forever?) that React was trying to get rid of in the first place (it's this problem that made people doubt the scalability of Angular applications, made them waaaay too complicated at larger scales).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It helps a lot, especially the unidirectional data flow part. I will make this as the correct answer later if no other answers are submitted.